# Find what is causing high CPU usage on Qubes OS

Tags: xen, qubes

In Qubes OS, processes are running in multiple VMs, so just running `top` on a VM won't necessarily tell me anything useful, if that VM isn't using the CPU very much. How can I find out which process(es) is/are consuming the CPU and causing my fan to spin at a high speed, regardless of which VM they happen to be running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open a *wide* Dom0 Terminal and type `xl top` (or `xentop`) to find the VM that is using the most CPU.
The tool displays one status line for each VM, including Dom0, and
it gives more accurate CPU usage numbers than `top` does.
In addition you can see the memory usage and number of read and writes to virtual disks as well.

If a VM has high CPU usage, then open a terminal in that VM, and type `top` to see which process(es) are using the most CPU inside that VM.

If appropriate, kill/exit them, and rinse and repeat if there is still high CPU usage on the machine overall.

(In my case, the problem was with the sys-usb VM after resuming from suspend, and the very act of opening a terminal in sys-usb somehow seemed to fix the problem!)